# Angular Material Design - not getting tabs

Tags: angular-material, angular8

I want implement MD tabs. Here is my very simple test code:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="system" routerLink="syspref"> Default Preferences </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="user" routerLink="userpref"> User Preferences </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

And here is my project configuration:

```
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.801.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.801.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.801.0
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.801.0
@angular-devkit/core              8.1.0
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.1.0
@angular/cdk                      8.2.3
@angular/flex-layout              7.0.0-beta.24
@angular/material                 8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                  8.1.0
@schematics/angular               8.1.0
@schematics/update                0.801.0
rxjs                              6.5.2
typescript                        3.4.5
webpack                           4.35.2
```

AS I understand Angular MD is installed.
But all get when I run the app is this:
[image]

Am I missing styles or something?

Thanks

Comment: Check this link and confirm whether you want it this way? : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dpxufm?file=src/app/tab-group-basic-example.html

Comment: Yes, something like this.

Comment: Can't figure out why it's not working in my code.

Comment: I have downloaded your example and it's not working at all. Not even compiling.

Comment: Can you provide the error?

Comment: I actually figured out why it wasn't working in my code. Your example uses just ne module why my real code has many. Going after your example I was importing Material stuff into the application module. Once I imported it into the actual implementation module it started working.